# MySQL Integer Storage Requirements

Tags: mysql, types, storage, int

In MySQL do the storage requirements for the `INT` datatype vary with the actual value stored in the table?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Why did you delete your answer?!

Comment: @Tomalak - He didn't believe it was good enough?

Comment: @Steve: Looks good enough to me. Sad to see it go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`INT` always uses 4 bytes.

`BIGINT` always uses 8.

If you don't require the full range of the `INT` type, you can save storage by using one of the other integer field types:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-types.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to save space, you can compress your table with **myisampack**. It will also optimize field type and length, and may convert a column from BIGINT to INT. But your table becomes read-only.

http://www.techrepublic.com/article/save-disk-space-by-compressing-mysql-tables/5852557